# How can I get all the filename of a directory in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

In Flex How can i get all the filename which contains in a directory in flex AIR.

Comment: Please take the time to check your previous questions and vote or mark them as answered.

Comment: Patrick as I am a new developer of flex so frequently i need help from stackoverflow. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use File() function

[Please Refer to this Site](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html) for More Info

Answer (score 0):

if dirPath:String is your directory path, then

```
var f:File = new File(dirPath);
var arr:Array = f.getDirectoryListing();
```

This gives you list of all files in the given directory. The elements of the array are File objects, each representing a file / dirctory in the given directory.